# Plotting piecewise functions in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the piecewise function below using `if` statements, and I keep getting the

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

message. All of my braces seem just fine to me, so I don't know where this is coming from. Any advice here would be appreciated. (Also, this is basically the first time I've done something like this in R, so please bear with me).

```
x.values = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)
n = length(x.values)
y.values = rep(0, n)
for (i in 1:n) {
x = x.values[i]
if (x <= 0) {
    y.values = -x^3
} else if (x <= 1) {
    y.values = x^2
} else {
    y.values = sqrt(x)
}   y.values[i] = y }
```

Comment: Is there something you're not showing us, because when I run your code, it complains there's no `y`.  Also, it might be that you have two `}` on one line:  see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without a loop by taking advantage of the fact that R functions are usually vectorized.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_classic())

dat = data.frame(x=x.values)
```

In base R, you can do:

```
dat$y = with(dat, ifelse(x <= 0, -x^3, ifelse(x<=1, x^2, sqrt(x))))
```

With `tidyverse` functions you can do:

```
dat = dat %>% 
  mutate(y = case_when(x <= 0 ~ -x^3,
                       x <= 1 ~ x^2,
                       TRUE ~ sqrt(x)))
```

Then, to plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I certainly appreciate your response, but part of the exercise is actually to specifically use "if" statements within a "for" loop to create the function. (Perhaps I should've mentioned this in the OP...)

Comment: Since this is an assignment, let me just give you a hint: Your code will run if you put `y.values[i] = y }` on its own line. But it won't give you the result you're hoping for. Think about what's happening when you assign `y.values = -x^3`, `y.values = x^2`, etc. each time through the loop.

Comment: Ok, so, I've tried a couple things, and got it to run per your suggestion (though, I'm still not exactly sure what why there had to be a separate line for y.values[i] = y) keep getting the error that "y.values" is not found. First, all of the assignments in the "if" statement, I changed from "y.values" to "y.values[i]" (thinking that maybe I needed to be assigning values for each element of the vector), but got the same problem. I also tried forcing the conditionals (so, saying if (x>0 && x <= 1) instead of just (x<=1)... which, I shouldn't have to do, since "else" implies "otherwise")...

Comment: I also flipped "y.values[i] = y" to "y = y.values[i]," because that's the order R likes to see, I take it (given the usual "<-" assignment operator). So far, I keep getting the same error. So, parsing the loop, element x_i from the vector x.values enters the loop and becomes simply "x." The first 21 x_i's will get "caught" in the first if statement because they're <= 0, get negated and cubed, then become the ith element of the y.values vector, and bypass the other two if statements, and get assigned to "y." Elements 22 through 31 of the x.values vector will bypass the first if statement...

Comment: ... (because they're NOT <= 0) and then get caught by the second if statement where they'll be cubed and become the 22nd through 31st elements of the y.values vector, then bypass the last conditional statement, and become y. And so forth... that certainly makes sense to me, but I guess not to R?

Comment: R doesn't "like to see" a particular order. `y.values[i] = y` assigns the current value of `y` to the ith location in `y.values`. `y = y.values[i]` assigns the current value of the ith location of `y.values` to `y`. Note also that in your initial code you ran `y.values[i] = y` after the if/else statements, but `y` had never been previously created or assigned a value.

Comment: The separate line for `y.values[i] = y }` was to avoid having two `}` on the same line (which was what was causing the error).

Answer (score 1):

When I ensure the newlines are in the right place, I don't get errors about unexpected symbols:

```
x.values = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)
n = length(x.values)
y.values = rep(0, n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  x = x.values[i]
  if (x <= 0) {
    y.values = -x^3
  } else if (x <= 1) {
    y.values = x^2
  } else {
    y.values = sqrt(x)
  }   
  y.values[i] = y 
}
```

However, what I do get is a complaint that `y` doesn't exist on the last line.

Since this is a homework assignment, I'll stop with this partial answer :P